# Debug entire Node.js code running on Docker

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, docker, visual-studio-code

I've setup Node.js with Docker and everything is working. I configured VS Code so I can do remote debugging and it's also working, but is there a way  I can debug code that was executed before the debugger got attached?

For example, in the image below, I can't debug line 3 and 9 because this code is executed when node is started and I can't attach a debugger without any node process running.

[image]

Here's my Dockerfile's CMD:

```
nodemon --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 src/index.js
```

Comment: If all you want to debug is those lines, can't you just run it Natively using the vscode node debugger?

Comment: Not exactly. Imagine i'm trying to debug a line that creates a file inside my container.

Answer (score 0):

You can start your instance and pause on first line with the flag `--inspect-brk`.
https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html#debugger_v8_inspector_integration_for_node_js

Or you can simply write a `debugger`statement on your code and it will pause once it reaches the statement line.